# With golang how can I generate a rsa certificates then export the private key to a pfx file and the public key to a cer file

Tags: go, ssl-certificate

I'd like to generate some certificates by golang, but stuck with a problem.

When I do that in php, it maybe like those codes:

```php
$privkey = openssl_pkey_new([
    'digest_alg' => 'des3',
    'private_key_bits' => 1024,
    'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA

]);
$csr = openssl_csr_new([
    "countryName" => "EN",
    "stateOrProvinceName" => "province",
    "localityName" => "city",
    "organizationName" => "org",
    "organizationalUnitName" => "org",
    "commonName" => "name",
], $privkey, ['digest_alg' => 'des3']);

$x509 = openssl_csr_sign($csr, null, $privkey, $days=3650, ['digest_alg' => 'des3']);

openssl_x509_export_to_file($x509, "/path/to/pub.cer");
openssl_pkcs12_export_to_file($x509, "/path/to/pri.pfx", $privkey, "password");
```

And now with golang I can only create the private key but don't know what to do next.Help me please and many thanks.

```golang
func main() {
    keyBytes, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, bitSize)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := keyBytes.Validate(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    dn := pkix.Name{
        Country:            []string{"EN"},
        Organization:       []string{"org"},
        OrganizationalUnit: []string{"org"},
        Locality:           []string{"city"},
        Province:           []string{"province"},
        CommonName:         "name",
    }
    asn1Dn, err := asn1.Marshal(dn)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    template := x509.CertificateRequest{
        Raw:                asn1Dn,
        SignatureAlgorithm: x509.SHA256WithRSA,
    }

    csrBytes, err := x509.CreateCertificateRequest(rand.Reader, &template, keyBytes)
    // how to do with csrBytes next?
}
```

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#CreateCertificate

Comment: Not that. I know how to create, but just don't know what to do with the return value next. I wonder how to save as *.pfx and *.cer

Comment: @yuchanns I think this might help you. It's for `*.pem`, but you'll get the idea.

https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/generate_cert.go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I resolved the problem by myself. Now I should write the answer for others face the same issue.

The solution is using [`software.sslmate.com/src/go-pkcs12`](https://godoc.org/software.sslmate.com/src/go-pkcs12) which provides function [`Encode`](https://godoc.org/software.sslmate.com/src/go-pkcs12#Encode) to encode given bytes data created from `x509.CreateCertificate`.

Look at the example codes below:

```golang
func main() {
    keyBytes, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 1024)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := keyBytes.Validate(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    template := &x509.Certificate{
        SerialNumber: big.NewInt(1),
        Subject: pkix.Name{
            Country:            []string{"EN"},
            Organization:       []string{"org"},
            OrganizationalUnit: []string{"org"},
            Locality:           []string{"city"},
            Province:           []string{"province"},
            CommonName:         "name",
        },
    }

    derBytes, err := x509.CreateCertificate(rand.Reader, template, template, &keyBytes.PublicKey, keyBytes)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    cert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(derBytes)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    pfxBytes, err := pkcs12.Encode(rand.Reader, keyBytes, cert, []*x509.Certificate{}, pkcs12.DefaultPassword)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // see if pfxBytes valid
    _, _, _, err = pkcs12.DecodeChain(pfxBytes, pkcs12.DefaultPassword)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := ioutil.WriteFile(
        "/path/to/pri.pfx",
        pfxBytes,
        os.ModePerm,
    ); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Everyone can find the source code in my github repo [yuchanns/gobyexample](https://github.com/yuchanns/gobyexample/tree/master/pkcs12)

Comment: Hi,
have you also explored how we can specify expiry date while creating certificate request? I was trying to read through some documents, but was not able to figure out how to do that.